# Missing file on XCode 4 showing the warning file://localhost/.../WaveView.h: warning: Missing file: /..../WaveView.h is missing from working copy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, xcode4.2

In my iPhone app I am implementing Audio Recording, It works on iPhone simulator/Device
and It says missing of file as below:

```
Missing File
file://localhost/.../WaveView.h: warning: Missing file: /..../WaveView.h is missing from working copy
```

and the file WaveView.h & WaveView.m shows red color in left slide bar and I revealed in finder to delete this file but that file is not existing on the app folder.

Can anyone suggest me to solve this problem

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only solution for your problem is copy the files back to your app. Make sure that you are copying to the project(obviously this is the best practice).

Comment: like! Yes! This is the best practice :D

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you added the file 'relative' to the project instead on 'copying' the file to the project. This issue is probably appearing because you moved the project and the file is no longer in the same relative position.

Just re-add the file to the project and copy it in to the project folder

Answer (score 0):

Implies your WaveView files are missing. Put them back. If you dont need them then remove referenceds from XCode.